# Visual Studio additional build options

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

The Visual Studio IDE offers Solution Configurations and Solutions Platforms, what I'd like to do is provide my own Solution Target drop down.  Currently what we are doing is just having multiple build configurations in the Solution Configurations drop down but it can get really sloppy after adding too many targets.

What we are currently doing is:

- DebugTargetA
- DebugTargetB
- DebugTargetC
- DebugSimulationTargetA
- DebugSimulationTargetB
- DebugSimulationTargetC
- EngineeringTargetA
- EngineeringTargetB
- EngineeringTargetC
- ReleaseTargetA
- ReleaseTargetB
- ReleaseTargetC

But I'd prefer if Solution Configurations could just be:

- Debug
- Engineering
- Release

And have another drop down (actually 2) that could just set some of the defines up for us:

- drop down 1: Simulation | Not Simulation
- drop down 2: TargetA | TargetB | TargetC

Is there any existing packages or easy ways of doing this? (VSPackages could be an option)

Comment: Well, of course.  Is that *really* want you wanted to know?  If you want to figure out how to program it then you'll have to RTFM.  Probably best to keep it simple.  Create your own project templates with File + Export Template.  Or write a little program that creates the .sln and .vcxproj files, they are pretty simple text files.

Comment: I've edited my actual question, thanks Hans, it wasn't _really_ what I wanted to know :)